# How do you parse nested comments in pegjs?

Tags: javascript, parsing, grammar, peg, pegjs

I was wondering how do you parse comments (say, a la Haskell), in pegjs.

The goal:

```
{-
    This is a comment and should parse.
    Comments start with {- and end with -}.
    If you've noticed, I still included {- and -} in the comment.
    This means that comments should also nest
    {- even {- to -} arbitrary -} levels
    But they should be balanced
-}
```

For example, the following should not parse:

```
{- I am an unbalanced -} comment -}
```

But you should also have an escape mechanism:

```
{- I can escape comment \{- characters like this \-} -}
```

This sorta seems like parsing s-expressions, but with s-expressions, it's easy:

```
sExpression = "(" [^)]* ")"
```

Because the close parens is just one character and I can "not" it with the carrot. As an aside, I'm wondering how one can "not" something that is longer than a single character in pegjs.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This doesn't handle your escape mechanisms, but it should get you started (here's a link to see it live: [pegedit](http://pegedit.cspotrun.org/?gistid=2c2d00ec4a11b5caaedc&peg_filename=nested_curly.peg.js&source_filename=source.txt); just click `Build Parser` and `Parse` at the top of screen.

```
start = comment

comment = COMSTART (not_com/comment)* COMSTOP

not_com = (!COMSTOP !COMSTART.)

COMSTART = '{-'

COMSTOP = '-}'
```

To answer your general question:

> > As an aside, I'm wondering how one can "not" something that is longer than a single character in pegjs.

The simple way is `(!rulename .)` where `rulename` is a another rule defined in your grammar. The `! rulename` part just ensures that whatever's scanned next doesn't match `rulename`, but you still have to define something for the rule to match, which is why I included the `.`.

Comment: Cool! Thanks. That helped a lot. I had seen the ! operator but I thought that it just didn't work. I know I understand that I actually had to include something for it to parse.